# How do I know if the version of Linux as well as distribution of Linux I am running uses xinetd?

Tags: linux, xinetd

Is there a specific file I need to check or is it a process I need to be looking at? If I am running inetd, do I need to disable it and run xinetd instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If xinetd is installed and running you should have /etc/xinetd.d directory with configuration files and an xinetd process running.
See: [how to tell if you're using xinetd](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-tell-if-your-linux-server-uses-xinetd-or-inetd-sever/). 
Which one you run is up to you, but you can't use them both simultaneously. [Xinetd](http://www.xinetd.org/faq.html) is supposed to be more secure and I think most of the current distros are using it now.